# 2D array data null?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I have created a program to accept input from user and will store in 2d array. Example situation, the user enter an input no of semester = 2; then the no of course also = 2;. My loop is working correctly, but the data is not store well.

The output :
null
null
null
input4

It should like this : 
input1
input2
input3
input4

Here my code :

```
BufferedReader inData = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    try {

        System.out.print("Enter no of semester : ");
        data = inData.readLine();
        noSem = Integer.parseInt(data);

        // Semester loop
        for(int i = 0; i < noSem; i++) {

            System.out.println("\n\tSemester" + (i + 1));
            System.out.print("Enter number of course : ");
            data = inData.readLine();
            noCourse = Integer.parseInt(data);

            // course details loop
            for(int u = 0; u < noCourse; u++) {

                System.out.println("Enter Course Code : ");
                System.out.print("Enter Course Name : ");
                sbjName = new String[noSem][noCourse];
                sbjName[i][u] = inData.readLine();

                System.out.println("Enter Credit Hour : ");
                System.out.println("Enter Marks : ");
                System.out.println("\n");

            }
        }

        for(int x = 0; x < noSem; x++) {
            for(int y = 0; y < noCourse; y++) {
                System.out.println(sbjName[x][y]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hint: You need one allocation before entering the loops, and on each iteration of external loop you should do another allocation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
BufferedReader inData = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

try {
    System.out.print("Enter no of semester : ");

    int noSem = Integer.parseInt(inData.readLine());
    String[][] sbjName = new String[noSem][];

    // Semester loop
    for (int i = 0; i < noSem; i++) {
        System.out.println("\n\tSemester" + (i + 1));
        System.out.print("Enter number of course : ");

        int noCourse = Integer.parseInt(inData.readLine());
        sbjName[i] = new String[noCourse];

        // course details loop
        for (int u = 0; u < noCourse; u++) {
            System.out.println("Enter Course Code : ");
            System.out.print("Enter Course Name : ");
            sbjName[i][u] = inData.readLine();

            System.out.println("Enter Credit Hour : ");
            System.out.println("Enter Marks : ");
            System.out.println("\n");
        }
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < sbjName.length; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < sbjName[x].length; y++) {
            System.out.println(sbjName[x][y]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly like i want, may i know why you make  `sbjName[i] = new String[noCourse];`

Comment: On each iteration *i* (for each semester), user enters the number of course given in the semester.
So each time, the number of courses (*noCourse*) might be different.
That's why we allocate array of size *noCourse* for all the courses of this particular semester.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
sbjName = new String[noSem][noCourse];
```

That statement creates a **new** array during **each** iteration. In other words: you are throwing away the array(s) that you created before; thus any information that you previously stored in those arrays ... is thrown away too!

You want to make that call only **once**; so you move it *outside* of your loops!

Comment: `noCourse` is different for each iteration, so for each iteration of the external loop, new allocation of linear array must be made.

Comment: After i moved it outside. No output display and cant continue to another input.

Comment: I actually wanted to further enhance my answer; to make more clear what you would need to do. But I got interrupted; but I see you got what you needed by now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you are recreating the 2d array each time you go through the first for loop.

to solve this, you need to define the number of courses available in the beginning:

```
    BufferedReader inData = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String[][] sbjName = null;
    String data;
    int noSem = 2;
    int noCourse = 3; // say there are 3 courses that are available

    try {

        System.out.print("Enter no of semester : ");
        data = inData.readLine();
        noSem = Integer.parseInt(data);
        System.out.print("Enter number of courses available : ");
        data = inData.readLine();
        noCourse = Integer.parseInt(data);
        sbjName = new String[noSem][noCourse];
        // Semester loop
        for (int i = 0; i < noSem; i++) {

            System.out.println("\n\tSemester" + (i + 1));
            System.out.print("Enter number of course : ");
            data = inData.readLine();
            int courseNum = Integer.parseInt(data);

            // course details loop
            for (int u = 0; u < courseNum; u++) {

                System.out.println("Enter Course Code : ");
                System.out.print("Enter Course Name : ");

                sbjName[i][u] = inData.readLine();

                System.out.println("Enter Credit Hour : ");
                System.out.println("Enter Marks : ");
                System.out.println("\n");

            }
        }

        for (int x = 0; x < noSem; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < noCourse; y++) {
                System.out.println(sbjName[x][y]);
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
```